# Issues with shared library when setting up Spinnaker Python SDK (PySpin) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, spinnaker, flir, pyspin

I plan on using PySpin on Ubuntu but I cannot get the code to compile with this as the only error:

I understand that shared libraries must be added to the correct system variables. However, I don't see any files named "libSpinnaker.so.4".

I am using Python 3.10 and I followed the directions specified in the README.txt. Install numpy, matplotlib, and then execute/open the wheel with pip. Please point me in the right direction if possible. Thank you!

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../AcquireAndDisplay/main.py", line 32, in 
import PySpin
File ".../AcquireAndDisplay/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySpin.py", line 15, in 
import _PySpin
ImportError: libSpinnaker.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

This was the error when trying to execute one of their sample python scripts.

Comment: How did you install spinnaker? Have you searched for libSpinnaker.so?